# JNI global reference leak and how to debug

Tags: android, memory-leaks, java-native-interface, native-code

I'm testing my app, and found a "GREF exceeds 2001" problem. For this particular case, I can see there are a lot of binders created in both system process and the app process using `dumpsys meminfo`. I have two questions: (1) Is binder leak specific to older versions of Android? (2) In general, how do we debug GREF problems (or native leaks)?

Comment: If 2001 is the number of global refs you are using, you are using far too many, by I would say two orders of magnitude. How many do you *think* you are using?

Comment: It seems that it is related to bug in Android 1.6 which leaks Binder instances.

Comment: I would have a good look at using WeakRefs instead if you have the choice. A bit more complex but no leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, in general, is a hard problem. And there's not much difference compared to debugging desktop Java applications that use native libraries. More details would be posted later.